# JAXB works differently on websphere or weblogic?

Tags: jaxb, websphere, weblogic

I have a problem deploying an application using JAXB on websphere. For exemple, on weblogic, there is no problem to add a simple java object containing just a string. On websphere it says that the class or none of its super class is known to this context.

"javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class ch.tie.iengine.server.method.Object_CreateECH0160$RefId nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:554)
    at ...

Or if i try to marshall an abstract class on weblogic, there is no problem. on websphere it says that the concrete class needs to have an @XMLRootElement annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of WebLogic 12.1.1, WebLogic switched to using [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) as the default [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) provider.  I believe WebSphere still uses the JAXB reference implementation.  This may account for the difference you are seeing.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/eclipselink-moxy-is-jaxb-provider-in.html

Answer (score 1):

That was a library problem because jaxb.properties was missing.